# Google Bigquery limit condition

Tags: google-bigquery

When I run my big query with limit 5 it returns more rows. This happens whenever i put limit greater than 3. For every limit it returns more rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can happen, if you are using BigQuery Legacy SQL and querying table with repeated field for example as below

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT request.parameters.* 
FROM [yourProject:yourDataset.yourTable]
LIMIT 3
```

What it does? It limits number of output rows to 3, but than it outputs all repeated values in those three rows thus you see more than 3 :o)
The way to check this is to run below and confirm that real number of rows output is actually 3

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (
  SELECT request.parameters.* 
  FROM [yourProject:yourDataset.yourTable]
  LIMIT 3
)
```

The best way to deal with this is to [`migrate to using BigQuery Standard SQL`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql)